# iRobot Create 2/Roomba 530 Screw size/thread?

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

I've looked everywhere I can think of to find this information, but haven't come across anything. Does anyone know what kind of screws I can use to replace the ones on top of my Roomba 530?

I realize that the Create 2 is technically a 600 series, but I would expect they were the same.

I'd like to replace the screws on my Roomba with standoffs so I can stick a mounting plate on top of it. (Additional sensors, CPU, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The screws in the top cover of the robot appear to be special plastic screws; I've never been able to find a good place to buy more. If you're careful with a pin vise (remove the battery first! Don't use a power drill!!), you can tap into the holes shown in the [Open Interface Spec](http://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf?la=en) section entitled Roomba Internal Screw Boss Locations with an M3 or 4-40 bottoming tap. I'd avoid the screws vertically aligned with the center of the robot, though; they're awfully close to other circuitry.